# Combine 2 arrays into 1 in React

Tags: arrays, reactjs, datagrid, material-ui

Say that I've the following arrays:

```
const headerArray = ["h1","h2","h3"];
const dataArray=[["a1","a2","a3"],["b1","b2","b3"]];
```

I want to combine them into an array like this:

```
finalArray= [
{
    "h1": "a1",
    "h2": "a2",
    "h3": "a3"
  },
  {
    "h1": "b1",
    "h2": "b2",
    "h3": "b3"
  }
];
```

How can I do this in React?
(I need this functionality in order to display an uploaded Excel table in Material UI datagrid in React)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can complete it by using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) like this.

```js
const headerArray = ["h1","h2","h3"];
const dataArray=[["a1","a2","a3"],["b1","b2","b3"]];

const finalArray = dataArray.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  const item =  curr.reduce((acc, curr, index) => (acc[headerArray[index]] = curr, acc), {});
  acc.push(item);
  
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(finalArray);
```

Or just [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) instead.

```js
const headerArray = ["h1","h2","h3"];
const dataArray=[["a1","a2","a3"],["b1","b2","b3"]];

const finalArray = dataArray.map(curr => 
                  (curr.reduce((acc, curr, index) => 
                      (acc[headerArray[index]] = curr, acc), {})));

console.log(finalArray);
```